# Hide navigation bar after using search bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, hide, uisearchbar

I have hidden my navigation bar in my table view controller, but after selecting the search bar and then dismissing it with Cancel it shows the navigation bar again. I tried

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
}
```

But it did not work, it did hide the navigation bar from the detail view though, but that was not desired.

In storyboard I have a tabBarController --> navigationController --> tableView --> detailview.

EDITED:

My code:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [_truckArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return 1;
    } else {
    return [_sectionTitles count];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        if (section == 0) {
            [_sectionTitles replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@""];
            [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
        return [searchResults count];
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
    NSString *sectionName = [_sectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *sectionArray = [_sections objectForKey:sectionName];
    return [sectionArray count];
    }
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
Item *item = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        item = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    NSString *sectionTitle = [_sectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionArray = [_sections objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    item = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: have u tried in - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar

Comment: Yes, but the navigation bar is still there.

Comment: is ur search bar goes to navigation bar on search?Can u post ur code how u initialise the search bar

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/

Answer (score 6):

If when you dismiss the search bar try to see if you are calling again the viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear method of your tableView an in there call your code to hide the navigation bar.

I know for sure that when you show a modal view, when you dismiss the view the viewDidAppear method is called, maybe here you have the same behavior.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

I hope this helps.

Happy coding.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but I am already doing this. I am not sure why it is not working. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Working perfect

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set `<UISearchBarDelegate>` in your view controller

or by ref..`self.searchBarRef.delegate=self`;

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
   if([searchText isEqualToString:@""] || searchText==nil) {
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

//OR use below delegate method

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
}
```

Keep below code at viewWillAppear or ViewDidLoad and check it.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Hope it fixes the issue...!

Comment: I tried it now, it is still not working. Very strange!

Comment: Does any of search bar delegate methods are calling..!

Comment: Does the issue lies with Not calling delegate methods of search bar or Not Able to hide navigation bar even You hide the navigation bar...?

Comment: The problem is that the navigation bar goes from being hidden to being visible after using the search bar, even though it is set to be hidden.

Comment: I added two lines of code. Keep it in view controller and check it..!

Comment: This made the navigation bar black instead

Answer (score 0):

*What about hiding the navigation bar on  `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` and enabling it again `searchBarTextDidEndEditing`, you just have to animate the frame of navigation bar to hide and unhide .*

```
 -(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{


                self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, -64, 320, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);
            }];

        }

    -(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{

                self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);
            }];
        }
```

**NOTE:-I have added hardcoded value for Y axis and width, it can be easily calculated as per navigation-bar frame and status-bar frame.**

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, it did not work. The navigation bar is still there.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Search Controller

-(void)initSearchController{
self.isSearchActive=false;
self.searchBarTimeline=[[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:self.searchBarTimeline];

self.searchBarTimeline.delegate=self;

self.searchBarTimeline.placeholder=@"Search";
self.searchBarTimeline.searchBarStyle=UISearchBarStyleMinimal;


[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

}    


#pragma mark - Tableview search
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
[self.searchBarTimeline setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
 [self.searchBarTimeline setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

self.isSearchActive=true;
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timecontact.userName contains[c] %@ OR timecontact.userSummary contains[c] %@", searchText,searchText];
searchTimelineResults = [[[[UIAppDelegate coreDataHelper] timelineFetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

if(searchTimelineResults.count==0){
    self.isSearchActive=false;
}
else{
    self.isSearchActive=true;
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Play with flag isSearchActive and reload data of tableview

Comment: please post ur  code, so we can find what is issue in that

Comment: You cannot achieve that with searchDisplayController, You have to write your own searchbar and implement it.That will not distrb the NavigationBar